# FeathersJS query using two $or but and'ed together

Tags: feathersjs

I'm trying to figure out how to generate the following SQL condition using Feather's REST query:

```
(color = 'blue' OR color = 'green') AND (sport = 'hockey' or sport = 'football')
```

This is what I've tried (based on the documentation):

```
?$or[0][color][$eq]=blue&$or[1][color][$eq]=green&$or[2][sport][$eq]=hockey&$or[3][sport][$eq]=football
```

But this generates the following:

```
((color = 'blue') OR (color = 'green') OR (sport = 'hockey') or (sport = 'football'))
```

I've tried different combinations and even nested `$or` statements but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it. Is this even possible in FeathersJS? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restructure this using `$in`.

```js
// Object
{
    color: {
        $in: ['blue', 'green']
    },
    sport: {
        $in: ['hockey', 'football']
    }
}
// String: ?color[$in][0]=blue&color[$in][1]=green&sport[$in][0]=hockey&sport[$in][1]=football
```

which generates:

`WHERE color IN ('blue', 'green') AND sport IN ('hockey', 'football')`